# Ionic: load same page with different parameters

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have a page which has a text input field and a button. Upon entering data in text input and clicking search a Api call is made with the input text and results are displayed below the button, Here is my code

template,

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="location"></ion-input>
<button (click)="onSearch()">Search</button>
<ion-list>
//display search results here
</ion-list>
```

Component,

```
//SearchPage
onSearch() {
    //api call to get list of restaurants in the location
}
```

User can also change the data in input and search again.This is working but when user searches two or more times and hits back button he will be navigated back to home page and not to the previous search.

Is there a way to push the same page("SearchPage" here) to navControl upon every click of search button by passing the input data ? So that the back button works as intended?

These changes worked for me
In component

```
OnInit() {
    location=this.navParams.get('data');
    //Api call using location fetched from navParams
}
onSearch(){
    this.navController.push(SearchPage,{data:this.location})
}
```

Comment: Can you show the `code` of your `page` `navigations` including `back` button functionality and etc.?

Comment: I tried calling ' navController.push(same page)' and it worked as i wanted.(added code to question)... But is it okay to push the same page again and again?@Sampath

Comment: This is not clear for me.Can you clarify it more? `This is working but when user searches two or more times and hits back button he will be navigated back to home page and not to the previous search.`

Comment: For example user searchs "Bangalore" first and next  he changes input to "Mumbai"  and searches.. Now if he press back I want to display results for Bangalore@Sampath

Comment: OK, Can you show the code of `back` button then?

Comment: Its the default back button behavior in nav tab.. I haven't implemented any@Sampath

Comment: When pressed `back` where it goes? `home.ts`?

Comment: Yes earlier it used to go to home.ts.. But with the changes i made it worked as I wanted... But Iam not sure its the best practice to push Same Page multiple times as I did in onSearch() method above@Sampath

Comment: We cannot tell anything without knowing the page transition.If you can put page names with your code then we can easily see those.

Comment: all above code is from SearchPage only @Sampath

Comment: Then how you come back to `search` page again from `home` page?

Comment: Like we reload the same state with different params in angular 4 routing, Can we push the same page with different params in ionic pages? is my question@Sampath

Comment: Actually my question is... from within a page say "page1" can I use navController.push(page1,{params}) with changedparams?@Sampath

Comment: Why do you need to do that kind of hack? Why can't you use built in `Searchbar` component as I mentioned below?

Comment: Iam not trying to filter the search bar here@Sampath

Answer (score 0):

According to your comments, I feel you're on the wrong path.You can easily use [**Searchbar**](http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#searchbar) with your app.

According to the above doc, you can do it as shown below.

*.html*

```
<ion-searchbar (ionInput)="getItems($event)"></ion-searchbar>
<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{ item }}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

*.ts*

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'search/template.html',
})
class SearchPage {

  searchQuery: string = '';
  items: string[];

  constructor() {
    this.initializeItems();
  }

  initializeItems() {
    this.items = [
      'Amsterdam',
      'Bogota',
      ...
    ];
  }

  getItems(ev: any) {
    // Reset items back to all of the items
    this.initializeItems();

    // set val to the value of the searchbar
    let val = ev.target.value;

    // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
    if (val && val.trim() != '') {
      this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
      })
    }
  }
}
```